# MediaRecorder records video only but can't playback

Tags: javascript, html, mediarecorder, mediastream

I'm using MediaRecorder to record the stream in a video tag. MediaRecorder works fine if the video has an audio track however when i remove the audio track to do a video only recording I can't play back the recorded webm file.

```
var options = {
   videoBitsPerSecond: 2500000,
   ignoreMutedMedia: true,
   mimeType: 'video/webm'
}
recorder = new MediaRecorder(new MediaStream(e.stream.getVideoTracks()), options);
```

If I was to guess I would say the recorded webm file doesn't have the framerate data so the playback just tries to play every frame a millisecond apart. Which is why I see a picture when I try to play the video but not the video playing.

Comment: In which browser? (with version)

Comment: @Kaiido chrome.

Comment: works for me on chrome 61 osX: https://jsfiddle.net/24zL77z3/

Comment: What OS are u using? I had the same problem with Debian, and it works under Win or OSX...

Comment: @Kaiido That works for me too. I simplified my problem, I'm recording H264 video from a webrtc call. I bet the frame rate isn't as consistent as it is when using a webcam.

Comment: @Polaris Windows 10 64 bit. I think this has more to do with H264 video and webrtc. Since I was able to run with Kaiido's jsfiddle example.